# How does jizya exactly work in the Islamic State?

Tags: islamic-state, islam

I have a few doubts over how jizya works in the Islamic State.

As far as I understand, christians and jews are allowed to "stay and not be killed" as long as they pay this tithe.

However:

- are they free to expatriate, if they want to? (assuming they already paid)
- what about atheists, or people from other religions?
- if someone claims to be christian, do they bother to check if that's true? How?

I've found [a source](http://www.khilafah.com/index.php/the-khilafah/non-muslims/15384-part-2-which-non-muslims-can-become-dhimmi-and-what-are-the-conditions-of-the-jizya) where they discuss three different ways to handle the "what about atheists and other religions" problem, but I didn't manage to understand which of these actually happen in reality.

Didn't found anything about the two other problems, mostly because I'm not sure what to google for…

*(since they are closely related, I posted them as a single question, but if you prefer for them to be split, no problem)*

Comment: As a question, this really is far more political than about the topic of Islam.  If you wanted to know about the Islamic basis for any particular known ISIS doctrine (when it's reasonable that it is (or claims to be) based on Islamic priniciples), that could work here but asking about what any particular state does or does not do (which may or may not have any direct tie to Islamic teachings, regardless of whether they claim to be an "Islamic" state or not).

Comment: when he said ' Islamic State', he may have meant  Islamic State only, not the   Islamic State currently run by ISIS. let him clarify

Answer (score 10):

Jizya is the tax given by non Muslims for the protection given by Islamic state. Number of groups are exempt from giving this like monks, poor, women, old people etc. So wealthy Muslims are required to pay Zakath and wealthy non muslims are required to give Jizya. Other than being a tax for government, one purpose of Jizya is that they recognize the state and is not revolting against it. This is clear from the verse about Jizya which says  "they pay the Jizya with willing submission, and feel themselves subdued" http://quran.com/9/29

As you pointed out in the link you posted, there are difference of opinions on whom Jizya would be collected. Some say it is all non Muslims, others say it is only people of book (that is Jews and Christians) and Majoos (fire worshippers).

Currently ISIS is accepting Jizya only from people of book. That is reason they didn't take it from Yazidis, so they were forced to convert or had to leave the area to avoid getting killed. Actually there is an hadith in Sahih Muslim ( http://sunnah.com/muslim/32/3 ), that states Jizya can be collected from polytheists. But ISIS decided not to accept Jizya from them, resulting in forced conversion, which is against Islam. See my answer here  https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/17080/intolerance-in-muslims/20240#20240

So to answer your question, what "actually happen in reality ?" , this depends on the group that is creating the Islamic state.